# Inscape E: Unmet dependencies

Tags: 20.04, dependencies, inkscape

I try install dependencies before compiling inkscape and I have got such a error:

```
 bash install_dependencies.sh --recommended
Downloading and installing dependencies. This may take some time.
+ [[ ubuntu == \d\e\b\i\a\n ]]
+ [[ ubuntu == \u\b\u\n\t\u ]]
+ sudo apt-get update -yqq
+ sudo apt-get install -y -qq build-essential cmake intltool pkg-config python3-dev libtool ccache doxygen git
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Why compile? Why not install by apt? Did you run `sudo apt -f install` as it is suggested?

Comment: I want only compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command helped me.
`sudo apt -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" --fix-broken install`